# An Excel search tool based on multiple user input

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and need some guidance in the following.

I have created a search tool and a data source each in a separate Excel file.
Below search code looks in de data source for a certain value (user input value in number or text format) and returns with a copy of the entire row where the data is found. The copied information is then showed in the search file.
At the moment the code uses input value from a single cell. In this case the cell is called “FILE_NAME”.

The intention is to have the code such that it uses the input of multiple cells, only filled cells, and returns with the rows corresponding to the input data.
Appriciate your help!

```
Sub Search()
  Call Searchfunction
End Sub

Sub Searchfunction()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'define workbook and worksheet to search.
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

'Open wb1 and ws1 and set (SEARCH workbook)
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws1 = ActiveSheet

'Open wb2 and ws2 and set (Data File)
 Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Paul Baghramian\OneDrive - APT CuttingB.V\APTC_Engineering\99-APTC-Drawing List\APT_Cutting_Drawing_List.xlsx")
 Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("APT Drawing List")

'empty output range
 ws1.Range("8:250") = ""

'get search value
 searchvalue = ws1.Range("FILE_NAME").Value = Range("FILE_NAME").Value
   
'define outputrow startnumber
 outputrow = 8

  'start searching for the value is column 1  (A to H) and rows 4 to 1000.
   For Column = 1 To 14

    For Row = 2 To 2000
    
    'get text from cell
    text_in_cell = ws2.Cells(Row, Column)
        
            'convert both the text in the cell as well as the searchvalue to lowercase
            text_in_cell = LCase(text_in_cell)
            'searchvalue = LCase(searchvalue)
    
        'if text contains searchvalue
        If InStr(text_in_cell, searchvalue) Then
            
            'copy the specific row A to H from sourcerange srange on source sheet to destination range drange on destination sheet Blad1
            Let srange = "A" & Row & ":" & "N" & Row
            Let drange = "A" & outputrow & ""
            ws2.Range(srange).Copy _
                Destination:=ws1.Range(drange)
            
            'go to next output row
            outputrow = outputrow + 1
        
        End If
    
    Next Row

 Next Column

'close dataset.
 wb2.Close

'all is done, go back to SEARCH sheet
 ws1.Activate

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: How do you want to select the cells? If the name range “FILE_NAME” is multiple cells, set the variable like `set searchvalue = ws1.Range("FILE_NAME")` and you can iterate through all the values of the range: `For each x in searchvalue`. Do you want to do a separate search for each value, or do you want to combine them?

Comment: Hi Christofer, there are total 14 cells and each can be filled with a different search criteria. The cells are located at row 2 from column A to N. I have renamed the cells as follows. A2 = FILE_NAME, B2 = SYSTEM_NUMBER, C2 = DRAWING_NUMBER, D2 = REVISION_NUMBER, E2 = SHEET_NUMBER, F2 = TITLE, G2 = SUB_TITLE, H2 = COMMENTS, I2 = DRAWING_DATE, J2 = CUSTOMER, K2 = PROJECT_ORDER_NUMBER, L2 = Dredger, M2 = Material, N2 = Dimensions.  The code is currently using only the value in cell A2 (FILE_NAME) to search in the data source. I like to have it such that it uses the values in other cells to.